# How to animate a metal backbone?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, bezier-curves

Hello i've made a cyborg (a human body with metallic parts) and i have alot of difficulties with the rigging (the metallic parts deforms when i dont want them to) and especially the backbone! there are several metallic vertebras attached to the back of the human, i made one vertebra and made an array modifier with a curve modifier
How can i avoid any deformation? Is it the curve that i need to parent to the rig?

Comment: To avoid modifications at all, you could apply that curve modfier. To avoid parts deforming you can adjust weights. Having at least a view of your rig and model, would help suggesting how...

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/XjMusyb.png
[link]http://i.imgur.com/hxFknTf.png

I modified the backbone to test another method, i dont have any curve modifier on my mesh

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43931

Comment: I see now: so the rig must deform the body, but the metallic vertebras should follow the deformed body they are attached to, but not be deformed by the rig, right?

Comment: Exactly! its a mix between organic and mecanic...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is what you could try, I hope it fits with your workflow, or at least inspires you to find a better way:

1. put the body in rest pose
2. apply the vertebras modifier (array+curve)
3. separate vertebras mesh into separate vertebras objects
4. then, create a vertex groups (1 vertex each) on the body back skin, one for each vertebra, which will get "attached" to that vertex later.
5. then I would create a "child of" constraint for each vertebra, with the right vertex group as "target"

eg: if this is your rigged body (here posed)

[image]

select the "body" and create (eg) two vertex group, one "skin" vertex each:

[image]

and

[image]

then "attach" each vertebra (here is a sphere) to its vertex group using the "child of" constraint (after adding the constraint, you may need to reposition the "vertebra" where it should be, if it goes elsewhere):

[image]

then, when you pose the rig, the body follows the rig, and the ver[image]tebras follow the body, without deforming.

here is my example .blend:
[image]

Note: parenting is not the same, will not work well, use this kind of constraint.

**edit**

after understanding better the rig/model pose, I expand to add details of what I intended...

preface:

- I reverted the rig to the "rest position"
- you created an "array" of 14 vertebras but not using the array modifier, instead you parented one base vertebra to a curve and used the "frame duplication" feature of such setup, setting the "path animation" frames of the curve to 14.

[image]

- since what I intended to do above needs 14 real vertebras, not duplicated ones, after setting the mesh "duplication" frames end also to 14 (it was 99, default probably), I used the "make duplicates real" comand, and removed the "base vertebra" parent to the curve.

[image]

and

[image]

obtaining 14 real vertebras, with no duplication

[image]

- then I've hidden all vertebras but the first 2, to keep the example simple to visualize (the whole model is really complex)
- after that, I went in edit mode of the body mesh, and created two separate vertex groups, 1 vertex each, each to be the "hook" for a single vertebra.

[image]

- then, I added to each vertebra the constraint "child of", targeted to each vertex group, and placed them where they should be in rest pose

[image]

in solid mode

[image]

from the side

[image]

- now, going back to posed mode, each vertebra sticks to and follows its vertex group, without deforming, but you may need to adjust something to make them move as you desire: the model spine moves quite a lot, and that move vertebreas also... maybe using vertex groups of more than 1 vertex blends the vertebra movement better ... I just tried to keep it simple.

[image]

here below you find the updated model with the 2 example vertebras seen in the screenshots above...

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cUeOR2y.png
http://i.imgur.com/eIYKXZp.png

Well... Its like... worse than before... i must have done something wrong!

Comment: ? are they still deformed? or do they move around? I can't think what could be happening, your model seems quite complex... I' looked your .blend, now, I can't understand how to pose the rig, though, every bone seems locked...? sorry I'm not that good at riging...

Comment: No they arent deformed but they are not at the right place! and they rotate strangely... for the rig you have to open the "N" window and go at the rig and click for the IK

Comment: I can't find that switch in the properties panel... maybe it comes with som addon?

Comment: Yes it is the addon rigify!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find that setting even after enabling rigify... if I click regenerate rigify buttons, the skeleton disappears... I'm so noob at this.. :)

Comment: let's se if someone else understand how to make me unlock this pose: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64984/cant-find-how-to-enable-ik-on-another-users-rigged-model-whats-the-catch

Comment: So now you know how it works?

Comment: yes, but atm I can't work on it... I'll try to do what I supposed above...

Comment: updated answer, this is what I suggested from the start, applied to your model, with lots of references... I hope it's clearer now... ;)

Comment: I dont understand... I did this before, what is the difference? The vertebras are still in a strange position and rotation...   
http://i.imgur.com/eHYNzCx.png

Comment: In your image I see some vertebras are upside down, you can just rotate them 180°, but some also get partly covered by the body mesh, in that pose... I recently followed another question (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65111/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-clothing-piece-will-animate-with-a-body-mesh/65136#65136) where there's a similar issue with cloths over a rigged body, and the answer points to a video tutorial that could help you... look all the video but don't miss the end part, where there are "buttons" that need to follow the body without deform... and a solution.

Comment: I think i found the solution! I made a triangle for each vertebra then parented the vertebra to the triangle, and all the triangles are parented to the rig by automatic weight! 
http://i.imgur.com/I5xK6Le.png