# Can't find how to enable IK on another user's rigged model, what's the catch?

Tags: rigging, rigify, pose-mode

I'm trying to help a user in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/how-to-animate-a-metal-backbone) , but he's using a complex posed human-body, and rigify. He posted the model here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43931

I would like to check how to solve his problems, but I need to change the model pose, it seems locked, there should be a sort of IK switch for the rig but I can't find where it is. I'm quite a rigging noob, sadly.

He told me hs's using rigify, but even after enabling it, I can't still pose this model... I'm using Blender 2.78, but could try older versions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bones that are visible by default in this file have all transforms locked.You have to make visible armature layers, that contains controlling bones. Here is the image, that shows this.[image]

Comment: Thanks... now I see what you show above, but I still can't see those rig layers button... should I do something special..? also, I have autorun disabled... if this could matter.

Comment: You should enable autorun, cause this bone leyers ui is done with code (rig_ui.py), that is in the file.