# How to make an empty follow a rigged mesh's movement?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am trying to animate a bug plushy. I have made a rig to my liking, but as I maneuver the rig the facial features (which are separate objects) don't follow along. I have tried parenting these other objects to the mesh I have already rigged and the armature itself. Is there a way I can make the empty follow the transform of a bone tip? I'm not sure how to go about this.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Blend File](https://www.mediafire.com/?4w833xlpzlvzc13)

Comment: it depends on how you wish those facial features to behave when the armature deforms the main body: if they are part of the same object parented to armature, either you don't assign them weights (and so they don't move) or you do and they are deformed - not necessarily just moved - by the armature pose... sometimes is better to use (eg) an empty vertex-parented to a specific body vertex (so it simply follows that vertex wherever), and then parenting the face feature to that empty. It depends. see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/how-to-animate-a-metal-backbone/64886#64886

Comment: btw, I tried to get your file but ...43 MB... no thanks.

Comment: @m.ardito How can I compress the file size? I really don't have much of anything that should be causing that, I have unused materials but I can't seem to get rid of them. The file is literally that model with the rig & like 2 empties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also common to keep the facial features as separate objects, and you can certainly use one armature to control multiple objects. The 2 most typical ways to do it is:

1)[SEPARATE OBJECTS] To have one of your bones (the head bone usually) have complete control over the features.  In this case the features would all move as a whole following the head bone, and further movement (e.g. eye rotation is done via keyframing the objects loc/rot.  To do this you would: select the armature, and in pose mode select the head bone (And only the head bone, so it is slected and teal) in object mode select one eye. holding shift select all the other facial features. Still holding shift select the armature last.  Let go of shift, hit ctrl P and choose 'bone'

2)[ONE JOINED OBJECT] Join the meshes as suggested above. Then create  separate bones for each feature. each of these bones is a child of the head bone in the armature hierarchy. each of these bones (e.g. bone.eye.L) has complete control of the feature using vertex group.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this:

1. Select your main mesh object.
2. Then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right click</kbd> to select the small facial features.
3. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them together.
4. Re-Parent the mesh with the armature then they will move with the mesh.