# Hook an object to a vertex

Tags: objects

Like the Title, is there a way to hook an object to another object's vertex(s) ? or any other method that produce the same result.

Comment: yes, one way is to use "child of" contraint, selecting the target object and a vertex group (put the target vertex on a vertex group of its own), like explained here, eg: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/how-to-animate-a-metal-backbone/64886#64886